# How to get the ID of a guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was making a bot that required me to fetch the ID of the guild where a "message" was sent lets say this is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx):
    # make a variable name guild_id and store the servers ID in it
    await ctx.send(guild_id)
```

Comment: You can simply use `ctx.guild.id`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctx.guild.id` like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx):
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    await ctx.send(guild_id)
```

This returns just the guild id that the command used. If you want a list, you can use this:

```
@bot.command()
async def ok(ctx):
    guild_id = []
    if ctx.guild.id not in guild_id:
        guild_id.append(ctx.guild.id)
    await ctx.send(guild_id)
```

This will return a list of guild IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command discord.Guild.id
The code will look like

```
    @bot.command()
    async def ok(ctx):
        # make a variable name guild_id and store the servers ID in it
        guild_id = []
        if ctx.guild.id not in guild_id:
            guild_id.append(ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.send(guild_id[-1])
        else:
            await ctx.send(ctx.guild.id)
```

This will make a list with all the guilds this bot was used in, and output the id of the guild the bot is currently in. For more information, [Check out the documentation for guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=gui%20d%20id#discord.Guild.id)
Hope this helps.

Edit: making the code more efficient since the comments specified a problem with the code.

Comment: Your guild_id is an empty array. You then get the length of it and are then trying to iterate over an `int` object which will throw an error. Iterating over an empty array also makes no sense. `discord.Guild.id` is accessing the variable of an non-instanced object of the class. You probably meant to write something like `ctx.guild.id`. You probably also meant to define the array `guild_id` but then you are also filling it? I can not make sense of your code. You should use [`client.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.Client.guilds)

Comment: This code won't work but even if you make it working, it's unefficient. Why did you made a for loop instead of just doing `if ctx.guild.id not in guild_id:`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys! I will edit my code so that its more efficient and makes sense.